# Rails 4.2.0 load error on Ubuntu using rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rbenv

I have installed multiple version of rails on my Ubuntu machine locally using Rbenv. Rails -v command works fine when I use it from some project. It shows the version like "2.3.8". But it shows error when I use Rails command from the main directory.
Rails -v or Rails new test_app:

> Blockquote

/**home/rashed/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/bin/rails:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /home/rashed/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rails-4.2.0/bin/rails (LoadError)
    from /home/rashed/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/bin/rails:23:in**

> Blockquote

.
Gem shows these installed rails versions (4.2.0, 2.3.8, 2.3.4)
I am using ruby "2.2.1p85".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also tried re-installing rails but it doesn't worked in this case. I tried this command

```
 $ gem install railties && rbenv rehash
```

and this worked for me like charm